# Android: Catch exception if mobile data isn't enabled

Tags: android, exception

Currently my app crashes if there is no internet enabled. I wanted to know how to catch the exception and have my popupdialog (below) show so they can then navigate to turn the data back on. I check the phone state like this:

```
public void CheckInternet() 
{
    ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connec.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    // Here if condition check for wifi and mobile network is available or not.
    // If anyone of them is available or connected then it will return true, otherwise false;

    if (wifi.isConnected()) {

    } else if (!mobile.isConnected()) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("You need to enable mobile data in order to use this application:")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("Turn on Data", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dialog.cancel();
                        Intent newintent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(newintent);


                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Main.this.finish();
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.show();
    } else if (mobile.isConnected()) {
        //nothing
    }
}
```

And I call the function at the beginning of onCreate() .

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create this boolean method and call it when you need to do something with required Internet connection:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And example could be the following:

```
if (isOnline()) {
    // Do network stuff
} else {
    // Show network error
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't use your code but your idea. I wrapped my function that used the internet in the check and it worked great! Thanks again.